# Desktop Refresh via dll

Tags: windows, batch-file, dll, vbscript, registry

My personal concern for this problem is because of a dynamic desktop program i am creating which the aim is for users to click a folder on a desktop and the contents of that folder becomes the new desktop. (I will post the code as an answer below as so to not convolute my actual question). However part of the code needs to kill and restart the `explorer.exe` process in order to reinitialize the desktop to display the new location.

Documentation of this problem is extremely difficult to find as its more technical than most people are willing to go for this particular field. [This man is trying to do the exact same thing as me except using autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154235-deep-structure-refresh-of-window-shell-explorer/), and [here users looked more into doing it vbscript side](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Refresh-desktop-or-explorer-shell-m30608.aspx) but both came to the same result of killing and restarting `explorer.exe` in order to update the desktop.

My issue with killing the `explorer.exe` process in a forceful manner can result in unstable systems and the actual killing of the process takes a longer time to reboot the desktop than whatever action occurs [when you simply move the desktop location](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/modify-desktop-folder-path-in-windows-8-8.1-computer.html). I want to know how i can update my desktop, by calling the dlls that update it, but from within a batch and vbscript hybrid.

EDIT:

Investigations to a command such as `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`, and later to the user32.dll dependencies has uncovered multiple uses of desktop functions, in which i assume is used to update the desktop in some form. If you would like to view this, [download dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and open it to this folder from within the program. (C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-user32_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.18123_none_be367a2e4123fd9d\user32.dll)

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is "shell extension" but I'm not sure if it's possible to overwrite the default behavior (opening) of any kind of desktop folder.

Comment: `If I can find what variable is being passed within the registry editor` What makes you think the registry has anything to do with opening folders on the desktop?

Comment: I could probably do a cheap fix where once the explorer is opened to the file, have a script copy that path and recreate the vbs file around it while closing the windows explorer.

As for me "Assuming" it has something to do with the registry, there are instances that explorer.exe is being called within the registry, the same executable that's used to visually move around in a program. If you want, i can show you such instances that are of interest to me and this topic.

Comment: In most Windows versions (up through 8.1, at least - I haven't used 10 yet), the desktop is simply a folder that has special meaning to the Windows shell (AKA Explorer). The only thing it has to do with the registry is that the location is stored there. There are specific API calls for retrieving the location of that folder, but none that I'm aware of that allow changing it via code. (FWIW, I think this is a horrific idea, especially if it's for other than your own personal PC. Like the physical desktop, you can (and should) pick up (drag/drop) files from the Windows desktop and move them.)

Comment: (continued). If you want to *dynamically* change things, simply  move the files from the existing desktop folder to a different one by way of your script, and then (by script) move the files from another folder into the existing desktop folder. Voila - desktop content replaced without mucking around with the registry and risking damaging your (or someone elses) OS.

Comment: What you suggest would actually save a lot of time in terms of having to restart the desktop every time, but the question is how it gets initiated. How is the program to know what desktop folder i clicked on and display that folders contents to the new desktop? If i make the change to the newly displayed desktop folder, i expect it to be absolute and not in a separate folder. Think of it like windows explorer but solely with the desktop. Do you know of the API that handles that retrieving? I would be interested in looking at it to see if i could piece together anything useful.

Comment: Kill `explorer.exe` process programmatically so that it's autorestarted, problem solved, no?

Comment: I already knew how to handle that within the batch file. It Still doesn't solve my main issue of how to pass the folder name that is clicked on the desktop to the script.

Comment: Don't know how to do this in vbs but you could make a c/c++ app which hooks WH_CALLWNDPROCRET events with SetWindowsHookEx(). Then listen for newly created windows in the explorer.exe process by checking the message being WM_CREATE. Finally, call GetWindowText() to get the name.

Comment: Thats identical to the batch script method i suggested and also appears to be much stabler ( does not rely on keypresses or timers to change the desktop.). However i do not know how to create c/c++ scripts so im assuming i would have to install some compiler or something to create it? It could save me some time in doing research on compilers, then the language itself, and the bug testing if you could provide some form of direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the manual changing of the desktop via batch and vbs hybrid. Its not perfect, but it provides a nice interface between moving in and out of directories to select the one you want to update to. **This uses the taskkill which i want to depreciate with something else.**

This is the initial batch script...

```
    @echo off
setlocal enableextensions
  ::Below computes the desktop location that the program will reference  
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo C:\HighestPrivelege\DesktopTools\findDesktop.vbs') do set "fold=%%a"
echo %fold%

::this loop will allow users to input new locations for the desktop by 
moving through a terminal. Wildcards and autotab completion is usable are 
and lack of input results in continuation of script
:loop
echo ################## %fold%
dir %fold% /A:D /B
echo _________________________
set loc=
set /p loc=[New Location?]
cd %fold%\%loc%
set fold=%cd%

IF [%loc%]==[] (goto cont) ELSE (goto loop)
:cont

::Below is the program that runs the regedit rewrite of the desktop variable 
for the current user. It passes the decided folder value from earlier as the 
new desktop.

cscript //nologo C:\HighestPrivelege\DesktopTools\setdesktop.vbs %fold%

::This restarts explorer.exe in order to reboot the newly created desktop 
location. I wish i didnt have to kill explorer.exe forcefully in the process 
but so far its the only way to make this program work.

taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
explorer.exe
endlocal
pause
exit
```

and the VBS script that follows...

```
Option Explicit
'variable invocation
Dim objShell, strDesktop, strModify, strDelete, fso, f, File, content, parthe, args, arg1
Set args = WScript.Arguments
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'this will take in the new desktop location.
set file= fso.OpenTextFile("C:\HighestPrivelege\DesktopTemporary.txt")
content = file.ReadAll
arg1 = args.Item(0)
parthe = ""&arg1&""
'The actual rewrite of the registry file containing the script lies below.
strDesktop = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Desktop"
strModify = objShell.RegWrite(strDesktop,parthe,"REG_EXPAND_SZ")
```

Activating the batch script will prompt user for where they would like to relocate their desktop to, and pass that variable into the VBscript to be rewrited to the registry. Upon VBScript completion, windows explorer will restart itself in order to reinitialize the new desktop location.

Until i can get a working model of the one where all i have to do is click/interact with the folder to initialize the program, this manual one will have to do.

Comment: I wonder if there is anyway to instead of opening a folder with explorer, that i can open it with the vbs script with argument 0=the folder clicked, so maybe what i need to do to disable windows explorer?